# restFB AccessToken cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

I am using restfb-1.6.12 and having a little trouble with the error "AccessToken cannot be resolved to a type" when using the following code:

```
import com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient;
import com.restfb.FacebookClient;

AccessToken accessToken = new DefaultFacebookClient().obtainAppAccessToken(MY_APP_ID, MY_APP_SECRET);
out.println("My application access token: " + accessToken);
```

I have the restfb-1.6.12.jar located in the WEB-INF\lib folder and I have the com.restfb classes folder located in WEB-INF\classes.

Answer (score 2):

Add this import to your class file:

```
import com.restfb.FacebookClient.AccessToken;
```

Comment: iam getting some output but its not the real access token. It is My appid appended with something